# Creating date range pairs in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, date-range

I have two datetimes between which I would like to generate regular intervals of 4 hours (excluding the last interval, which can be less than 4 hours if there are less than 4 hours between the previous timestamp and `end`).

I am stuck on interval generation with `pandas.date_range`, which only returns the `end` timestamp.  For example:

```
import pandas
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime(2021, 4, 2, 20, 40, 0)
end = datetime(2021, 4, 4, 18, 20, 0)


dates = pandas.date_range(start=end, end=end, freq='4H')
dates

DatetimeIndex(['2021-04-04 18:20:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='4H')
```

The aim is to generate a list of datetime pairs such as:

```
[['2021-04-02 20:40:00', '2021-04-03 00:40:00'], ['2021-04-03 00:40:00', '2021-04-03 04:40:00']...['2021-04-04 16:40:00', '2021-04-04 18:20:00']] #last pair can be cut off by `end`.
```

What am I doing wrong in the syntax and how would one go about generating a paired list of intervals from using `pandas.date_range` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a typo (`start=end`) that caused `dates` to have only 1 value.

But fixing the typo only gives you a flat range of dates. If you want those nested pairs, you could shift `dates` by 4 hours and `zip()`:

```py
dates = pandas.date_range(start=start, end=end, freq='4H')
shift = dates + pandas.Timedelta(hours=4)

pairs = list(zip(dates, shift))

# [(Timestamp('2021-04-02 20:40:00', freq='4H'),
#   Timestamp('2021-04-03 00:40:00', freq='4H')),
#  (Timestamp('2021-04-03 00:40:00', freq='4H'),
#   Timestamp('2021-04-03 04:40:00', freq='4H')),
#  (Timestamp('2021-04-03 04:40:00', freq='4H'),
#   Timestamp('2021-04-03 08:40:00', freq='4H')),
# ...
```

Or for a list of lists instead of list of tuples:

```py
pairs = list(map(list, zip(dates, shift)))
```